# Hartl Rails Tutorial 5.3.4: 'read': Is a directory @ io_fread) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

On Hartl's Rails Tutorial, the instructions are to generate a template test with `$ rails generate integration_test site_layout`

I am getting the error 
`/Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:73:in 'read': Is a directory @ io_fread - /Users/AlfonsoGiron/sample_app/public/assets (Errno::EISDIR)'` followed by multiple lines of 
`from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1`  .. etc etc

So I can see its pointing to 'assets' in the directory. Not sure what I am supposed to do though to fix the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or comment out the following line of code in `config/environments/development.rb` file:

```
# config.assets.manifest = Rails.root.join("public/assets")
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you sir !

Comment: I actually was not. I just skipped it.

Comment: Glad to know that this answer solved your problem :)

Comment: What does commenting this out do? Any citation for this?